# What does "the house Quidditch teams" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> Malfoy certainly did talk about flying a lot. He complained loudly about first years never getting on **the house Quidditch teams** and told long, boastful stories that always seemed to end with him narrowly escaping Muggles in helicopters.  ... ...

I think the noun word '*house*' is used to modify '*teams*' in this case, otherwise it would have been written as something like: *the house **of** Quidditch teams*.

However, I don't know what it means in this context. I guess that *the house teams* mean *the home teams*, maybe? What does "**the house Quidditch teams**" exactly mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this context, "house" refers to Hogwart's Gryffindor, Ravenclaw, hufflepuff and (drum roll please) Slytherin. Each of the group is called as house in Hogwarts and each house has a Quidditch team made up of their members.

A umble hufflepuff here :)

Comment: Your second sentence is confusing: the *team Quidditch team*? I would state that *house Quidditch team* means *the Quidditch team of the house*.

Comment: @choster I couldn't find where the _team Quidditch team_ located.

Comment: You say "*house* more or less means *team* here" except that it doesn't; it indicates the affiliation of the team.

Answer (score 2):

One of the [definitions of house](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/house) is

> [countable] British English in some schools, one of the groups that children of different ages are divided into to compete against each other, for example in sports competitions

In the Harry Potter books, all students are broken into houses. Malfoy is saying that "first years" or first year students never get chosen to play on the  Quidditch team for a house. I think that he is "complaining" because Harry, a first year student, actually made it on to the team, or is trying to get on the team and Malfoy doesn't like him.

Answer (score 1):

'House' in the above sentence refers to a group. The source of the sentence is one of the Harry Potter books (I don't recall which one). All the students in the school were exclusively divided in different groups, and these groups were called 'houses'.

Each of those houses had a team for playing Quidditch, which is a fictional sport created by the author. That's what the term "the house Quidditch teams" refers to.